# Obtaining float from division between NSIntegers

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nsinteger

I have two NSInteger variables called "domande" and "corrette". I have to execute this operation with them: corrette*10/domande. I want the result to be a float variable, so I declared a "voto" variable as so: "float voto = corrette*10/domande;" . When I output the value of "voto" with NSLog I get an approximated value of the result followed by ".000000".

Here's the code:

```
NSInteger domande = [numDomande integerValue];
NSInteger corrette = [numRisposteCorrette integerValue];
float voto = corrette*10/domande;
NSLog(@"float value is: %f", voto);
```

When I assign to "domande" a value of 7, and to "corrette" a value of 4: voto=5.000000
Instead it should be voto=5.71...

How can I have the division return not an integer type converted to float, but directly a float type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than converting integers to floats, you could just get floats in the first place:

```
CGFloat domandeFloat = [numDomande floatValue];
CGFloat corretteFloat = [numRisposteCorrette floatValue];
CGFloat voto = (corretteFloat / domandeFloat) * 10.0f
NSLog(@"float value is: %f", voto);
```

Answer (score 9):

Simplest way is to do:

```
float voto = 10.0f * corrette / domande;
```

By making the first argument a `float`, you guarantee that the others will be promoted as well and that intermediate and final results will not suffer truncation.

You could achieve a similar result by casting `corrette` to a `float` but I tend to prefer simplicity where possible.

Answer (score 4):

NSInteger does not have a method called floatValue. NSInteger is just an int. Instead, the solution would be:

```
CGFloat domandeFloat = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: numDomande] floatValue];
CGFloat domandeFloat = [[NSNumber numberWithInt: numRisposteCorrette] floatValue];
CGFloat voto = (corretteFloat / domandeFloat) * 10.0f;
```

Comment: Actually the most correct way would be to use numberWithInteger as the source numDomande is a NSInteger, not an int

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert the NSIntegers to a float type first:

```
float voto = (float)corrette*10/(float)domande;
```

Comment: [corrette floatValue] is not right - you can not send a message to not id type. Maybe you meant "(float)corrette" ?

Comment: Ah yes, I meant to cast :) I was a bit too quick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can cast "10" from int to float by writing it as "10.0"

```
  float voto = corrette*10.0/domande;
```

or

```
float voto = ((float)corrette*10) / (float)domande;
```

Operation "/" is returning type of it operands - 5/4 will return int result 1 because 5 and 4 are int, and 5.0/4.0 will return 1.25, because 5.0 and 4.0 are interpreted as float values. So you should manually cast type of input variables `corrette` and `domande` to float

Comment: That's not casting 10 to a float, it's using the nearest binary representation of 10 as a floating point number. No conversion is done, and thus no cast.

Comment: well, yes, this "cast" means "change type of 10 from int to float so it will be float from the beginning"

Comment: But that's not what a cast is in C, fundamentally the two are quite different.